# JQuery how to know out of all select which has lost focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have form for which I want to apply some validations on all text fields and Select fields. I want to know when the blur event is called it is raised by which field. I am using the below given code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("select").blur(function() {
                // alert("ID "+,$(this).attr('id'));
                var selected = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');

                var selectedTabTitle = $($("#tabs li")[selected]).text();

                skip_test(selectedTabTitle);
            });

            $("input").blur(function() {
                var selected = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');

                var selectedTabTitle = $($("#tabs li")[selected]).text();
                skip_test(selectedTabTitle);
            });
        });
```

Comment: sooooo.... whats your problem?

Comment: Well I am new to JQuery, say for example I have 3 Select with id=1,id=2,id=3 I want to know the ID which currently lost focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` should always point to the element which fired the event

for example `$(this).addClass("failedValidation")`

Also if you can add a class to all the selects and inputs you will not need to repeat your code.  If you can't you can define the function elsewhere and just refer to it in the `blur()`

e.g.

```
var doMyBlurStuff = function () {
     $(this).addClass("failedValidation")
};

$("select, input").blur(doMyBlurStuff);
```

Comment: but when I use $(this).attr('id') it just fails. As you can see in the posted code I have commented that alert statement

Comment: That fails because you've got a comma in there.
replace it with: `alert("ID "+$(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: @user2634485 No problem - we all do it (Feel free to mark it as the correct answer though ;) )